# Pakistan offers a visa on arrival to Turkish tourists holding a Schengen/UK/US visa. What if I am a dual Turkish/British citizen?

Tags: schengen, uk-citizens, dual-nationality, pakistan, turkish-citizens

I have obtained the information from [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=TR&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=PK&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C)

A further question is whether it would be possible to get a UK visa in my Turkish passport, to avoid any such ambiguities in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try talking to the Pakistani Embassy to find out if presenting a British passport at the same time as your Turkish one might count as "having a British visa". It might depend on the exact legal definition.

Getting a UK visa when you are already a UK citizen is going to problematic, even if it is possible, and may make someone suspicious of why you are doing it. You could also try to obtain a Schengen or US visa with your Turkish passport, both of which should be possible. It's also possible (though not necessary) to obtain a US visa with a British passport.

However the point of the exercise seems to be to avoid getting a Pakistani visa in advance - but to do it you have to apply for another visa (in advance). Unless there is a really good reason it would seem to be simpler to just apply for an advance visa from Pakistan.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose it's a little ambiguous. Do you think my best bet would be to contact the embassy in Turkey or my local one in the UK? Not that I have any immediate plans to visit Pakistan, but it would be helpful to know for future reference.

Comment: Can/do uk citizens need/get Schengen sticker visa?